# is $\frac{dx}{dz} + \frac{dy}{dz} = \frac{d(x+y)}{dz}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

asking this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495177/difficulty-in-solving-first-order-pde-yxzz-x-xyzz-y-z2-1) few days ago, I first saw that "trick" in the given answer. that trick enabled me to solve the question pretty easily (not the solution given), by adding the 2 equations:
$$(1):\frac{dx}{dz} =  \frac{y+xz}{z^2-1}$$ 
$$(2):\frac{dy}{dz} =  \frac{x+yz}{z^2-1}$$ 
$$(1)+(2):  \frac{d(x+y)}{dz} =  \frac{(x+y)(z+1)}{z^2-1}$$ and from there it was easy to solve the question.

However I still wonder if that was "legal" move to assume that:

$$\frac{dx}{dz} + \frac{dy}{dz} = \frac{d(x+y)}{dz}$$

I have to wonder what is the meaning of this ?  in what circumstances that legal move ?

Comment: you are leveraging the linearity of the differential operator so $\dot{(x+y)} = \dot{x} + \dot{y}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always a legal move.  Part of what the "linearity of the derivative" tells us is that
$$
\frac{d}{dz}(x(z) + y(z)) = \frac{dx}{dz} + \frac{dy}{dz}
$$
for any differentiable functions $x(z),y(z)$.